# Where did all the furniture that was in the villa come from?

Tags: the-best-offer

So was Billy the owner of all that furniture in the villa in [*The Best Offer*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1924396/) or where did it all come from?

Answer (score 2):

When Claire disappears, Virgil gets to a local bar and asks if someone has seen her. He meets Nana, a woman in a wheelchair, who turns out to be the real owner of the villa (and of all the forniture) and also the real Claire. The woman says she rents her house to movie producers, Claire and Robert.